# Visual Studio 2017 v15.5 Aspnet Core 2.0.3 fails to debug on IISExpress

Tags: visual-studio-2017, iis-express, asp.net-core-2.0, visual-studio-debugging

After I recently updated my visual studio 2017 installation from `15.4.5` to `15.5` I have lost the ability to hit breakpoints in my aspnet core 2.0 applications. The configuration is in debug any cpu.

While this works fine on kestrel (Debugging as a consoile app), on IISExpress it does not hit my breakpoints.

As a sidenote the weird thing here is it seems to have the debug symbols loaded on runtime (the breakpoint is correctly highlighted) and no warning.

**Environment:**

```
Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.16299
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.2\

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 2.0.3
  Build    : a9190d4a75f4a982ae4b4fa8d1a24526566c69df

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017

  Version  : 15.5.0
```

I have already tried to repair visual studio but the problem persists

Comment: I also opened a ticket with the visual studio developer community [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/162968/aspnet-core-203-fails-to-debug-on-iisexpress.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After careful inspection of my last commit after I updated to 15.5 I noticed that I had an unintentional change to my `launchSettings.json` file located under my project `Properties` folder. There was a new `use64bit` setting added and was set by vs to `true`.

**I had to set it to false** in order for visualstudio to work with debugging on iisexpress. Below is my current state of the IIS Express profile in launchSettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:20202",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "use64Bit": false
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, you could mark it as the answer. Thanks for your sharing:)