# Dot Net Core 2.1 is not running on IIS Express

Tags: .net-core

I am using VS 2017 Community and installed dot net core 2.1. I have created one test MVC project in dot net core. It is working fine if I publish this in local IIS and Command prompt use dotnetrun command.  But I need to use this through f5 in IIS express debug mode. I am getting the following error:

> unable to start process dotnet.exe

My VS is updated. I installed VS in the D drive instead of the default C drive due to space issues.

Comment: It's worked for me after reinstall Visual Studio Community 2017

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Close the Visual Studio and delete the project.lock.json file located in your project directory
2. Restart the Visual Studio as an administrator.

Comment: Hi, I delete the .vs folder , created again new mvc app in dot net core , run VS always in administrator mode, but no luck , my dot net core 2.1

Comment: Try this: Paste this command in run  `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WebsiteCache` and then delete your website folder.

Comment: I have delete all the code in cache but still error unbale to connect IIS

Comment: Check if this post helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47699101/visual-studio-2017-v15-5-aspnet-core-2-0-3-fails-to-debug-on-iisexpress/47699514#47699514

Comment: If I use   "use64Bit": false then error getting can't start process C:\programfiles\dotnet\dotnet.exe